# Update SQL datatable at a Specified Time in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I made a web api using entity framework codefirst method. The api communicates with a database that has many tables in it. I need to update a column value in a table at a specified time say after 1 hour using the web service. The coding is in c#. Help me please

Comment: Use SQL Server agent or Windows Scheduler. You can't do that by EF alone.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://hangfire.io/ for making tasks and background jobs, It is very powerful and has dashboard where you can monitor everything (success, fail, when the job will run again) .. and you can control the job to be recurring.